# Is this a good practice in multithreading in android?

Tags: android, multithreading

I have a thread that will run background and after that thread instantiate a string value, 4 more thread will run inside of that thread..

Is this a good practice in Threads base on android coding?

```
String name = null;

Thread a = new Thread(new First());
Thread b = new Thread(new Enemy());
Thread c = new Thread(new Enemy());
Thread d = new Thread(new Enemy());
Thread e = new Thread(new Enemy());
a.start();

class First implements Runnable {
    public void run() {
         name = "TARZAN";
         b.start();
         c.start();
         d.start();
         e.start();
    }
}

class Enemy implements Runnable {
    public void run() {
         System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName() + name);
    }
}
```

Is this a good practice performing a 4 runnable classes inside from a first thread?

Comment: This is not really multithreaded. You are not `start`ing those threads, you just `run` them on the `First` thread.

Comment: ah yes updated the codes to start(), is it a good practice? starting a thread inside a thread? because i tried it now and its working

Comment: Android has a lot of specialist multithreading classes you should read up about fwiw

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Threads don't run inside threads.  But what you're doing isn't spawning off 4 new threads-  you're just calling them as methods inside your first thread.  To spawn them as new threads you need to use .start(), not .run().  So if .run() is really what you want then I'd say it's a bad idea because there's no reason to make those threads at all.  If you really wanted to use .start() and launch a new thread, I'd say its fine so long as you have a good reason for doing it.

Comment: so its ok running multiple threads inside a threads? but syncronized method is more effective than waiting 1st thread to complete and starting other thread?

Comment: If a large amount of the work done by the multiple threads can be done at the same time, then yes synchronize the parts you need and you should be done faster.  If you're just going to wrap the entire thread in a synchronized block, then no you'll just slow things down.  Its perhaps a little unusual to need something like that, but I can see a few use cases.

Comment: Gabe Sechan i tried it again error doing .start() inside another thread, what is the problem? Does thread dont start inside a thread?

Comment: Threads can start inside other threads just fine.  Most likely your error is elsewhere, check the logcat.

Comment: or the thread b,c,d,e should be run in main thread? so il use handler? and run b,c,d,e to mainthread using handler?

Comment: i found "cause by: java.lang.IllegalThreadStateException: Thread already started." the error is met when i go back to that activity, should i destroy thread after the thread is finish?

Comment: You need to make sure not to call start on it twice.  I'm not sure where you're starting a, but if its in onStart or onResume, you want to do it only the first time.  Or you want to make 5 all new threads.

Comment: ah i put it in onResume hehehe its ok now i put it in onCreate hehe tnx!

Comment: Gabe Sechan i have followup question, what if vice versa using combination of Thread and Asynctask, i start a thread and in that thread inside i execute the asynctask is it ok? an also vice versa i execute an asynctask and inside i started a thread is it ok also?

Comment: An AsyncTask actually uses a Thread object to do what it does.  It just adds some extra code in it to call onPostExecute on the UI thread when its done.  So no difference.

Comment: hehehehe tnx Gabe your the best hehehehe